# Change LinearLayout width in DrawerLayout?

Tags: android, xml, layout

How can I change params of a LinearLayout inside a DrawerLayout?

I've tried it with:

```
LinearLayout linearLayout;
```

after onCreate:

```
    drawerLinearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer);

// drawer is the id of the linearlayout, where I want to change its params

DrawerLayout.LayoutParams lp = new DrawerLayout.LayoutParams(100,100);
linearLayout.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

the xml is like:

```
        <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/layout_drawer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                tools:context=".Main" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/drawer"
                android:layout_width="240dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
    </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

There is no error, but the size of drawer is not 100 x 100 - it takes the whole width and heigth :S

EDIT:

```
    public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    LinearLayout drawerLinearLayout;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    drawerLinearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer);

        int mode = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;

        if (mode == 1) {

DrawerLayout.LayoutParams lp = new DrawerLayout.LayoutParams(2,2);
drawerLinearLayout.setLayoutParams(lp);

        } 


}}
```

Comment: eh you've got 2 variables that you seem to be mixing up, `linearLayout` and `drawerLinerLayout`. That code wouldn't run.

Comment: what i have to change that it can work ?  thx u

Comment: Post more code so we can see what you're actually doing